# Real time plotting of data stream: Python vs Java

Tags: java, python, performance, plot, real-time

I have a small question that might be answered by a more experienced programmer than me.

I have to plot in real time two streams of data. In the end I need to build 5 different plots because in each plot I need to show different unit measures.

The first stream contains 4 values and one timestamp, the second stream has one value and one timestamp.

So, my idea is to run two threads that handle the two different streams which are received with different time intervals(6s the first and 1s the second one). Both threads should be able to receive the data and update the graphs.

My question is: which language do you think would be better between Python and Java, to implement this?

My fear is that using Java will result in a very slow UI.

It would be nice to have an answer supported by some considerations.

Thank you.

Comment: I'd recommend using python because it's plotting libraries are more accessible and straightforward.  This is only my opinion, but I've tried to build plotting apps in JAVA to no avail.  Also, this question is likely to be closed for being too opinion-based.

Comment: As Adam said, this is an opinion-driven question. If you want to use pure languages, I'd say both are pretty much the same, though. I cannot say about libraries much.

Comment: Python and Java should both be fast, but as mentioned previously, Python has good plotting libraries. PyQtGraph is well worth checking out, or Bokeh.